# Update report / drush up issue

Tags: 7, drush, updating

I'm experiencing some odd behavior with D7's update report. When I view the update report it can only determine the status of roughly 5 or so modules/themes. The ones that it finds are random and each refresh reveals a different list of statuses that it can determine. The list reveals all enabled modules but majority of them are grey with "No release found" for the status. `Drush up` behaves the same, except that it only returns the random 5 or so modules that it can find a status for.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Could it be that drupal.org is not responding and the issue is with drupal.org? It's really painful because the elegance and ease of `drush up` is no longer relevant when you have to run it 20 or so times to update modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the update manager reports 'no release found', it typically means you installed from a git (formerly CVS) checkout. If you did do this, you'll need to run the [Git deploy module](http://drupal.org/project/git_deploy) to properly track module versions.

If you didn't use direct git checkouts, but rather, downloaded normal releases from Drupal.org, it may be a bug, which should be reported with as much detail about your setup as possible in the [Drupal 7 issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=bug&version=7.x&component=All).

**Edit**: you may also be experiencing [this Drush issue](http://drupal.org/node/1002658).

Comment: Yes, it's most likely that bug. I'm seeing that too. If there are CVS or GIT checkouts, newer Drush versions recognise that and explicitly tell you to install cvs_deploy or git_deploy modules.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with Drush 4.4. Upgrading to Drush 4.5 solved this problem for me.